# Cyclic Reactivity Pattern in Meteor

Tags: javascript, url, meteor, reactive-programming, meteor-blaze

**The use case (tl;dr):**

On a search page, the user picks 0 or more 'markets' from a dropdown. The search results then filter to only show results which contain at least one of those 'markets'. Alternatively, the user can visit a URL with '?markets=A,B,C' query parameters set, to see results filtered to those markets. Of course, when the user picks options from the dropdown, the URL must be altered accordingly, so that they can bookmark/share that URL to share that view with someone. Herein lies the issue - we want the URL to update when the dropdown does, and the dropdown to update when the URL does, creating a cyclic dependency. How can we implement this such as to not set off an infinite loop when one is changed, as I am currently experiencing?

**Technical implementation:**

There are two templates: `search_page` and `search_filters`. The latter is a component included in the former.

In `search_page`, there is a helper `searchFilterArgs()`, which reactively gets the value of 'markets' from the query params (using `universe:reactive-queries`), and sets the data context for `search_filters` accordingly. It also passes a `setFilters` callback to the component. When the component calls the callback, `search_page` sets the workflow parameter in the URL to the passed value.

```
Template.search_page.helpers({
    searchFilterArgs(){
        const instance = Template.instance();

        const splitOrEmptyArray = function(filter_key) {
            if (UniUtils.url.getQuery(filter_key)){
                return UniUtils.url.getQuery(filter_key, false).split(',');
            } else {
                return [];
            }
        };

        return {
            setFilters: instance.setFilters,
            //get each query parameter as a non-reactive source, '' if not set, then convert to array
            selectedMarkets: splitOrEmptyArray('markets'),
        }
    },

...
});

Template.search_page.onCreated(function() {
    this.setFilters = (key, value) => {
        if (UniUtils.url.getQuery(key, true) !== value){
            UniUtils.url.setQuery(key, value);
        }
    };
});
```

In the `search_filters` component, there is an autorun on `Template.currentData()` that sets the dropdown to the 'markets' value in the data context. There is also an 'onChange' handler for the dropdown that calls the 'setFilter' callback with the value when the dropdown is changed.

**Observed behaviour:**

When the page is loaded, workflows is initialized to be empty. Then, I choose a market ("Sales") from the dropdown. The page then enters an infinite loop of changing the URL and changing the dropdown. Upon setting breakpoints, it was revealed that after I changed the dropdown value, the callback fired with the correct value, and the URL query parameters were set correctly. Then the component's data context is changed, which somehow causes the dropdown onChange handler to fire, but with the value "", rather than "Sales".

**Workaround:**

For now, I've changed the `searchFilterArgs` helper to retrieve the URL query parameters in a non-reactive way. Hence, when the page is first visited with a certain URL, the market parameter is passed in to the `search_filters` component. After this, any time the dropdown in the component is changed, the callback is fired, and the URL changed. Since the URL is retrieved non-reactively, this doesn't trigger a consequent change in the dropdown. It works fine for our previous use case, where the URL would only be set when opening the page, and not changed by the user after that. However, we now have code that will change the URL parameters on behalf of the user, and the filters should update accordingly.

Do you have experience with circular dependencies like this in Meteor? Is there a pattern to tackle this problem?

(I'm using Meteor 1.3.2 and Semantic-UI for the dropdown).

Comment: So what you really want to do is store a state in the URL. Correct? There is an article about that here: https://meteorhacks.com/meteor-ui-pattern-keeping-app-state-in-the-url/

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right @JanJoukeTjalsma. I did see that article before writing my implementation, but the article benefits from using UI elements that have two 'onChanged' handlers: one for when the user has explicitly clicked a button or link to  change a value, and one where the program has set the class of a link to be active, for example. In my case, the program isn't able to distinguish user-initiated changes from URL-initiated changes to the component, hence the problem.